# interactive queue for command line tasks windows

Tags: windows, job-scheduling

Sorry if this question is a bit vague. I don't know the right technical terms.

Basically in my research group we use a shared windows machine with a lot of RAM to run models, using remote desktop to access it from our own computers.

It would be great if we could build a queue so that we get the most use out of the machine, especially if we could then rearrange the order once it is up and running. Often someone will want to run say 50 runs of a 2 hour model, and someone else will just want to run once and check the results immediately, so they should get priority, but it's a pain stopping and starting large sets of runs.

We run models via command line, any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You could store the total time each user has spent on the computer and it would also be a good feature to let the users estimate the time they intend to use the computer. The queue could be built based on these data and if it is possible, when the estimated time is left 110%, then automatically kick out the user and allow the next to use the computer. I think you should implement a very basic system without too much effort. When all of you see it, you will have ideas about the optimal direction where the project should be headed.